# How to add the value from an input box to an array and then output its contents?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, socket.io

How can I go about adding the value of an input box into an array and then display the contents of that array?
This is what I've come up with and I'm not sure why it's not working - the console.log doesn't post anything to the console, either.

```
var user = user;
if (!user) {
  user = prompt('Please choose a username:');
  if (!user) {
    alert('Your name has been set to "Anonymous"');
  } else {
      alert('Your name has been set to "'+ user +'"');
  }
}

var items = [];
function userArray() {
    items.push(user);
    return false;
    console.log(items);
    }

socket.on('onlineUsers', function (data) {
      $('.dispUser').html(items);
    });
```

The rest of the code in the file is below, just in case it helps... (changed the return statement, as per the first answer)

```
var user = user;
if (!user) {
  user = prompt('Please choose a username:');
  if (!user) {
    alert('Your name has been set to "Anonymous"');
  } else {
      alert('Your name has been set to "'+ user +'"');
  } 
}

var items = [];

function userArray() {
    items.push(users);
    console.log(items);
    return false;
    }

socket.on('onlineUsers', function (data) {
      $('.dispUser').html(items);
    });

//Counts the number of users online
socket.on('count', function (data) {
  $('.user-count').html(data);
});

//Receives messages and outputs it to the chat section
socket.on('message', function (data) {
  $('.chat').append('<p><strong>' + data.user + '</strong>: ' + data.message + '</p>');
  $('.chat').scrollTop($('.chat').height());
});


//SENDING OF THE MESSAGE
//Submit the form through HTTPS
$('form').submit(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  // Retrieve the message from the user
  var message = $(e.target).find('input').val();

  // Send the message to the server
  socket.emit('message', {
    user: user || 'Anonymous',
    message: message
  });

  // Clears the message box after the message has been sent
  e.target.reset();
  $(e.target).find('input').focus();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Answer

Your implementation is fine, but you have a bug which is preventing it from working as you've described.

The call to `console.log(items)` does not print anything, because that line of code never runs.

When you return from a function, the subsequent lines of code will not be ran. You should `return` as the last line within your function, or wrap it in a conditional.

For example:

```
function userArray() {
  items.push(user);
  console.log(items);
  return false;
}
```

## How to debug

Learning the techniques to figure this issue out yourself is an invaluable tool. You can leverage a debugger, such as the Chrome Devtools, to add breakpoints to your code. These  will allow you to stop execution on a particular line, view the value of variables, and step through the remaining lines of code.

Doing so would make it clearly visible that the line of code is never running.

Find more details here: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript

Comment: This was a little Chrome trick I didn't know about - thanks.
Indeed, the function is not running, so now I'll have to figure out why.

Comment: Well, that is because you are not calling it. Just as you're calling the various `prompt`, `alert`, `Array#push` and `Console#log` functions, which are declared and part of the Javascript language; you will need to call the `userArray` function which you have defined. You'll want something like this: `userArray()`.